# Chained fat arrow in mapDispatchToProps get me an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

> Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

I am trying to chain fat arrow functions in a `mapDispatchToProps` but it doesn't seems to work.

Container and Action creator :

```js
// Actions Creator
const inputChange = (name: string) => (
  e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>
) => ({
  type: INPUT_CHANGE,
  name,
  value: e.currentTarget.value
});

// Dispatch
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  inputChange
};

// Connect
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(SignUp);
```

Dumb component

```js
const SignUp = ({ inputChange }) => (
  <input
    type="password"
    placeholder="Password"
    onChange={inputChange('password')}
  />
);
```

Maybe some parts of this code seems a little strange because I removed some of my `types` to not add extra pointless code.

Anyway the error come from the `mapDispatchToProps`, it seems like it's ok with a single fat arrow but when I start to chain them I get this error (even if they return an object).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error mentioned `actions` must be plain objects but when you chain the functions, you are actually passing a `function` (the next one on the chain) and not an `object`.

The problem here for you is that you want to pass an extra argument in addition to the actual `DOM` event, like the name of the `input`, i.e: "password", "user" etc...

Then why not just give the `input` a name and grab it in the action creator function (same as you do with the `value` attribute).

Your form can look something like this:

```
const Form = ({ inputChange, form }) => (
<div>
  <input name="user" onChange={inputChange} type="text" value={form.user} />
  <input name="password" onChange={inputChange} type="password" value={form.password} />
</div>
);

const mapState = state => ({
  form: state
});

const mapDispatch = {
  inputChange
};

const ConnectedForm = connect(
  mapState,
  mapDispatch
)(Form);
```

And inside your action creator:

```
const inputChange = ({ target }) => ({
  type: INPUT_CHANGE,
  payload: {
    value: target.value,
    inputName: target.name
  }
});
```

and your reducer can handle it, something like this:

```
const reducer = (state = {user: '', password: ''}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INPUT_CHANGE: {
      const { inputName, value } = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        [inputName]: value
      };
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**Running example:**

```js
// mimic imports
const { createStore } = Redux;
const { Provider, connect } = ReactRedux;


const INPUT_CHANGE = "INPUT_CHANGE";
const reducer = (state = {user: '', password: ''}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INPUT_CHANGE: {
      const { inputName, value } = action.payload;
      const nextState = {
        ...state,
        [inputName]: value
      };
      console.clear();
      console.log('store', nextState);
      return nextState;
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const inputChange = ({ target }) => ({
  type: INPUT_CHANGE,
  payload: {
    value: target.value,
    inputName: target.name
  }
});

const store = createStore(reducer);

const Form = ({ inputChange, form }) => (
<div>
  <input name="user" onChange={inputChange} type="text" value={form.user} />
  <input name="password" onChange={inputChange} type="password" value={form.password} />
</div>
);

const mapState = state => ({
  form: state
});

const mapDispatch = {
  inputChange
};

const ConnectedForm = connect(
  mapState,
  mapDispatch
)(Form);

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ConnectedForm />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const root = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(root, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.1/redux.min.js
"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/4.4.10/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following syntax.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    inputChange: () => {
      dispatch(inputChange("value"))
    }
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a function from your action which is not acceptable. Dispatch without middleware only accepts plane Object and not a function.

Either use middleware like Thunk or saga or change your logic to return object and not function like below

**ACTION**

```
// Actions Creator
const inputChange = (name: string, value: string) => ({
    type: INPUT_CHANGE,
    name,
    value
});
```

**COMPONENT**

```
const SignUp = ({ inputChange }) => (
    <input
        type="password"
        placeholder="Password"
        onChange={(e) => inputChange('password', e.target.value)}
    />
);
```